# Searching a nested data structure for 2 attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have the following data structures

```
export class BudgetGroupInfo {
    name: string;
    bcInfo: BudgetCatInfo[] = [];
}

export class BudgetCatInfo {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    bcAccounts: BCAccountInfo[] = [];
}

export class BCAccountInfo {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

What I need to be able to do is find which `BudgetGroupInfo` contains both `BudgetCatInfo.name` and `BCAccountInfo.name`

This is what I have so far and it works, but I feel like this isn't the most efficient want to do this.

```
getGroupInfo(budCat: string, account: string, budgetGroupInfo: BudgetGroupInfo[]): BudgetGroupInfo {
    let groupInfo = null;

    budgetGroupInfo.forEach(infoGroup => {
      infoGroup.bcInfo.filter(bcInfo => bcInfo.name == budCat)
      .map(bcInfo => bcInfo.bcAccounts)
        .forEach(accounts => {
            const acctInfo: BCAccountInfo = accounts.find(acct => acct.name == account);
            if(acctInfo) {
              groupInfo = infoGroup;
            }
          });
      })

    return groupInfo;
  }
```

1. First I go through the groups and find which ones have the specific `budCat`
2. I take the valid `BudgetCatInfo` and `map` the `bcAccount` array
3. I search that array and look for the specified `account`
4. If I find it then I set it for return.

Just a note that there won't always be a result and there will never be multiple matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this is an inefficient way to do this search. Even if the `groupInfo` is found in the first iteration of each loop, you still go through (almost) every single element.

First a couple comments on your code:

1. The return type is lying to me. The function doesn't return `BudgetGroupInfo`. It returns `BudgetGroupInfo | null`. The fact that this doesn't complain means that you don't have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) on. In my experience, this is the single most helpful feature available. It will let TypeScript tell you about a whole class of errors that it otherwise ignores.
2. `filter.map.forEach` is fine if you know only a few elements will be looped over, but if you end up having a lot of data, this will end up taking 3x the time. I don't find it that helpful for readability here, so I'd just pull the checks into the loop function.
3. TypeScript is generally pretty good about figuring out what variable types are. You don't need to manually type the result of `Array#find`.

The main trick for optimizing this is to make use of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and change the outer `forEach` into a `find`. Here's how I'd write your function:

```
function getGroupInfo(budCat: string, account: string, budgetGroupInfo: BudgetGroupInfo[]) {
    return budgetGroupInfo.find(group => {
        return group.bcInfo.some(info => {
            if (info.name !== budCat) return false;
            return info.bcAccounts.some(acct => acct.name === account);
        });
    });
}
```

There are a few subtle differences:

1. This returns `undefined` instead of `null` if there is no result. If this is a problem, it's a straightforward fix.
2. I removed the return type of the function. TypeScript can infer it easily in this case, and it will still be correctly inferred if you turn on `strictNullChecks`
3. If there is multiple matches (I know you said there wouldn't be but...) my version will return the first match, while yours returns the last match.